# How do I inherit the title bar options on my Window Controller

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, inheritance, titlebar

I am building a Cocoa OS X app, and I have hidden the title bar, close, minimize, resize options on the Window. It is working for the initial window and the view controller that follows. However, when the view controller "shows" another view controller, the initial view controller is closed. When it closes, all my title bar options go with it, and the title bar appears on the new one again. I want every view controller to have the title bar hidden. I'm not sure how to do this or where exactly to put this code `self.window!.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true` so it applies to all view controllers/new view controllers? Or is there a specific code I could put inside each view controller to override the title bar? I am pretty new to Swift. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why the initial view controller is closed when the view controller shows another view controller